# How to upgrade my createElement function such the property and values inside the style tag can be written in the form of objects not strings?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have created a function that creates an element and attaches attributes and value to it :

```
 var createElement = function(sel, att, val) { 
     var a = document.createElement(sel);
         if ( sel === "input" ) {
          a.value = val; 
         }
         else {
        a.innerHTML = val; 
        }
     document.body.appendChild(a) || 
     document.documentElement.appendChild(a);
     for( var key in att ) { 
     a.setAttribute( key, att[key] ); 
     }; 
   return a; 
  };
```

To call it I do :

```
 createElement("h1", null, "Hello"); // Does the work 
 createElement("input", null, "Hello"); // Does the work
```

So, not you may ask then where the problem is ? The problem is in adding property and value of the style attribute. I want to write the code something like this :

```
  createElement("h1", {
     style: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#008eff",
        padding: "20px"
     }
  },
  "Hello"
  );
```

But, with the function I made, I have to write something like this :

```
 createElement("h1", {
    style: "color : white; background-color : #008eff; padding : 20px;"
 }, 
 "Hello"
 );
```

I want to write the styles as objects not strings ! Yes, I want to upgrade my piece of code ! Can this be done ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of an attribute you're passing is an object, use `Object.assign` to assign it to the attribute of the object:

```js
var createElement = function(sel, att, val) {
  var a = document.createElement(sel);
  if (sel === "input") {
    a.value = val;
  } else {
    a.innerHTML = val;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(a) ||
    document.documentElement.appendChild(a);
  Object.entries(att).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (typeof val === 'object') {
      Object.assign(a[key], val);
    } else {
      a[key] = val;
    }
  });
  return a;
};

createElement("h1", {
    style: {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "#008eff",
      padding: "20px"
    }
  },
  "Hello"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use att[key] for other case of attributes, in this case i used att['style'] like this:

```js
var createElement = function(sel, att, val) { 
     var a = document.createElement(sel);
         if ( sel === "input" ) {
              a.value = val; 
         }
         else {
            a.innerHTML = val; 
         }
     document.body.appendChild(a) || 
     document.documentElement.appendChild(a);
     for( var key in att ) { 
         if (att['style']!==undefined) {
           stylekeys = Object.keys(att['style']);
            val = "";
            stylekeys.forEach(styleatt => {
                val +=  styleatt+": "+att['style'][styleatt]+"; ";
            })
            a.setAttribute( key, val );   
          }         
     }; 
   return a; 
  };
  createElement("h1", {
     style: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#008eff",
        padding: "20px"
     }
  },
  "Hello"
  );
```